# Port conflicts in starting test-network of Hyperledger Fabric using fabric-samples folder

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm a new starter and have been struggling for a while about these port errors
When I run ./network.sh in the directory: fabric-samples/test-network
the following port errors occurred:

```
    yujindeMBP:test-network yujin$ ./network.sh up
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'cryptogen'
LOCAL_VERSION=2.3.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.3.0
/Users/yujin/fabric-samples-with-bis/test-network/../bin/cryptogen
Generating certificates using cryptogen tool
Creating Org1 Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org1.yaml --output=organizations
org1.example.com
+ res=0
Creating Org2 Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org2.yaml --output=organizations
org2.example.com
+ res=0
Creating Orderer Org Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-orderer.yaml --output=organizations
+ res=0
Generating CCP files for Org1 and Org2
Creating network "net_test" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating orderer.example.com    ... error
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... 

Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... error
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED        STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
6feb86580f43   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           1 second ago   Created                                                    orderer.example.com
dbfae1aa4c11   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   1 second ago   Created                                                    peer0.org1.example.com
d0367a0d6089   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   1 second ago   Up Less than a second   7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
```

It seems the orderer, the org1 and the org2 are using the same ports 7050 and 7051, they got conflicted with each other. I have thought I can avoid these port errors by running docker. However, it seems that I'm wrong. I checked the docker environment before I run ./network.sh and I'm sure no other processes are running in the same time.

```
yujindeMBP:test-network yujin$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

The docker's processes table is clear before I tried to start the test-network.

I'm really confused and need your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `docker ps -a` This list all the active container.
Remove containers using the command `docker rm -f [container_id/container_name]`
once all containers removed then bring back your network.

If you're still facing the issue then go to your **crypto-config-org1.yaml**, **crypto-config-org2.yaml**, **crypto-config-orderer.yaml** edit and change the ports. Also you can ask question on https://chat.hyperledger.org/

Comment: I have removed other containers, but the errors are not fixed. I will try to modify the .yaml files. Thank you.

Comment: You can add ports section in YAML file as follows    ports:
      - 7051:7051

Comment: Thanks. Finally I solved this problem by restarting my computer

Comment: Forgot to tell you sometimes docker doesn't respond, so basically we need to restart the docker.